# Split very long character string into smaller character blocks with character overlap

Tags: python, bash

I have a long string of characters that I need to split into smaller chunks, but the chunks need to overlap. The length of the output string and overlap should be variable.

Example:

Starting with this in a text file:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
```

With the output being written like this:

```
---------------------
---------------------
---------------------
```

Comment: This is confusing because your example is just a single character repeated, so it is unclear how it overlaps. What if the string were ABCDEFGHI... etc?

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for responding.
I just wanted to make my example as simple as possible. I was trying to get across the idea that the strings will mostly overlap, but shift register by X.

Comment: For a simpler answer I would look at what @msw wrote; the next step is to use list comprehensions, as I outlined below.

Comment: But that doesn't get across the idea that the strings overlap, since there is no way to tell where each ---- starts. (Simpler doesn't always mean clearer!)

Comment: Just for the record, you gals/guys are amazing. Much obliged.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean something like:

```
def get_overlapped_chunks(textin, chunksize, overlapsize):  
    return [ textin[a:a+chunksize] for a in range(0,len(textin), chunksize-overlapsize)]
```

**Explanation**

Here I use a list comprehension, that just gets the indices that the output strings should start at `[0, step, 2*step,..., len(input)-chunksize]` where `step = chunksize-overlapsize`, and then returns the text at these locations, of length chunksize.

**Usage**

This function can then be used as follows:

```
textin = ''.join(open(FILENAME, 'r').readlines()) # text as single line

CHUNKSIZE=10
OVERLAPSIZE = 2    

chunks = get_overlapped_chunks(textin, CHUNKSIZE, OVERLAPSIZE)

fout = open(FILEOUT, 'w')
fout.writelines(chunks)
```

Comment: Hi Mutzmatron, 
Thanks for the response! Sorry to be dense, but where does the output go? I added f = open("textin", "r") below the def, but I fail to grasp how to add an output.

Comment: `def ...` is used to define a function, and it returns a list of strings, so you could use it, e.g. in `writelines` function of a file. I'll edit the code a little more...

Answer (score 2):

Given a string `s`, you can get a subsequence using **slices**:

```
>>> s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> s[0:5]
'abcde'
```

where the slice gives you the 0th character up to (but not including) the 5th character. The `range(start, end, step)` function gives a list of numbers starting at `start` up to `end` increasing by `step`

```
>>> range(0, len(s), 6)
[0, 6, 12, 18, 24]
```

combining the two gives you something like

```
>>> for i in range(0, len(s), 6):
...     print s[i:i+8]
... 
abcdefgh
ghijklmn
mnopqrst
stuvwxyz
yz
```

because the slice operation is "forgiving" it still yields a short answer on the last line for which there are less than 8 characters from `s[24:34]`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash:

```
length=20
overlap=3

while read line ; do
  idx=0
  while [ $idx -lt ${#line} ] ; do
    echo "${line:idx:length}"
    ((idx+=length-overlap))
  done
done < "$infile"
```